# AngularJS - send array in state params

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, uiview

I can able to send one value in state params from html using

```
<a ui-sref="index.manageInvitees({id: event.id})">
```

And can use in controller

```
$scope.event.id = $stateParams.id;
```

If it's array of elements not working for me

```
<a ui-sref="index.manageInvitees({event: event})">
  <i class="fa fa-users"></i> Add Invitees
</a>
```

And If I want take it in controller

```
$scope.event = $stateParams.event;
```

Not able to get. How can I get these values?

Comment: you can check it on the example, they use array in  `<li><a ui-sref="other({bar: [4,5]})">other({bar: [4,5]})</a>`http://plnkr.co/edit/r2JhV4PcYpKJdBCwHIWS?p=preview

Comment: I checked your code. Thanks for your example. I want like this, please refer plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/VcNtuQ6leOygnhSb0vIj not working for me